# News by CommerceLab magento module

Tags: php, magento

I am in trouble with [News by CommerceLab](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab-3436.html) module for Magento.

I put my news on homepage of my ecommerce, all works fine, but when I click on a news title, the browser returns me the message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object in app/design/frontend/iflavour/default/template/clnews/newsitem.phtml on line 2
```

On my code, on row 1, I have:

```
$item = $this->getNewsitem()
```

Of course, there is something wrong in initialize the getNewsitem class, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

How is this?

```
<?php $items = Mage::getModel('clnews/news')->getCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <?php echo $item->getTitle() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```